How can OAuth_2 be implemented with Hotwire/Stimulus in Rails?
It seems the Oauth buttons for Google and Facebook don't play well with Turbo. They load initially but any change implemented by Turbo seems to remove the buttons.  I'd like to use Stimulus to inject the buttons where needed on the site but I'm not finding any examples of how to do it.

My solution for Google Oauth2:
html
<div class='mb-1' data-controller="google-api">
  <div id="google-login-button"></div>
</div>

google_api_controller.js
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    
    // Insert a script tag in header
    if (!document.getElementById('google-gsi-client')) {
      const fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      const js = document.createElement('script');
      js.id = 'google-gsi-client';
      js.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }

    // reload button on turbo load
    document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: '8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      });
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("google-login-button"),
        {
          width: 230,
          height: 50,
          longtitle: true,
          theme: "dark",
          size: "large",
        }  // customization attributes
      );
      google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    });

  }
};


My solution for Facebook Oauth:
html
<div class='mb-1' data-controller="facebook-api">
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="" data-layout="" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

facebook_api_controller.js
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {

    // Insert script tag in header
    if (!document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {
      const fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      const js = document.createElement('script');
      js.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      js.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: '1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v19.0',
      });
    };

    // repaint button on turbo load
    document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    });

  }
};

